# I am trying to do a Boolean cut here; but there are some weird shading issue going on. How to fix that?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, shaders, topology

Here, I am trying to make a Boolean cut, but their are some shading issues going on.

[image: screen shot showing shading artifact]

Comment: The boolean virtually changes your topology, but could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Hi, @moonboots I have uploaded the file on pasteall.org/blend. I am also providing the drive link here to download the blend file. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PBOSC_kYNGgCqLlrVSWPkzvbg_O7I5Ag/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please let me know the solution

Comment: I could fix it if I applied the boolean but I'm not familiar enough with complicated non-destructive objects, I hope someone will help